# Git pull into specific directory from another directory with in the same repository

Tags: git

My repository directory structure similar to the following

```
app/
  .git/
  components/
    component-a/
    component-a-v2/
```

I would like to pull the latest from component-a/ into component-a-v2/ while working on component-a-v2/

What would be the best way of doing this?

I've tried `-C <path>` but I can't figure out the correct way of using this for my purpose

Comment: I don't think you are using git jargon correctly.... and then it's difficult to understand what you mean/want. So.... what you are calling a _repo_ is more likely a _branch_, right?

Comment: Oh.... or `component-a`/`component-a-v2` are submodules or subtrees, perhaps?

Comment: component-a/ and component-a-v2 are folders within the same repository

Comment: Sorry to be nagging, @Ash but, unfortunately, that's not correct. repos do not hold folders... they hold commits, references, etc. You might find folders inside commits (and references like branches/tags point to those commits).

Comment: ah ok @eftshift0 I've updated the terminology from folder to directory, I hope that's more accurate

Comment: You should either merge or rebase so that you can work with the real _history_ of the other branch where you want to bring stuff from.Maybe you are used to other VCSs where this might make sense but it's not the way that you should handle things with git.... anyway, there you have the way to do it, it you still feel like it.

Comment: Had to delete the comment above the one before this because I had made a litle mistake: Ok, that was not really relevant and you are not getting the gist of my comment.... anyway, let's try to move forward by _trying to guess_ what you really want. So you want the latest from `component-a` which is a directory in the project and I guess you mean the latest from _another_ branch? And you want to have everything else the way it is in your working tree? It's possible to do with `git checkout some-branch -- component-a` _however_ that's not the normal way to update your stuff...